# Keep settings in branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I begin to use git for software development.

I have a project on github. This project also involves some user-settings stored in dedicated settings-files.

On github the settings should be empty (like this)

```
### Settings:

## Your name
$name = "";
## Your email adress
$email = "";
## and so on
```

However, I also have the project running on my computer (or server). My personal version of the project should have all settings filled out.

I would like to have two branches for that. The personal branch should contain all my settings. The master branch should be the one where I develop the software and which I upload to github.

I would like to merge the master branch into the personal branch from time to time to keep my system up-to-date. However, whenever I try to merge the branches, my personal settings get lost.

Is there a way to do this or am I just doing something wrong (what)?

Comment: Could it be that you are (ab)using your build directory also as the producting/test directory? Those should be different things.

Comment: why should they be different? in the end, that means I would have to do all changes again after finishing testing. Thought one of the many advantages of git is that this is not necessary.

Comment: It is common to split testing from production, even the build-type would have to differ and the installed program should end up in some standard location and read the configuration from some standard configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your personal branch, you could keep:

- the GitHub config file unchanged (with no value), but with a different name (`config.template` for example)
- a "value file" with your personal value
- a "smudge" script able to generate the actual config file using the template one and your personal values

That script is triggered on any `git checkout` as a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571358/what-is-the-right-way-to-maintain-a-version-for-the-server-with-only-config/10571580#10571580).

[image]

That way, you can merge `master` onto your personal branch as many time as you want, your config values will not be modified.

Comment: Pretty kludgy to have to do it like this. It would be better if git simply had a way to force merge conflicts on some kinds of files, which would trigger the 'ours' merge driver. Somewhat related: Raymond Chen's ["The merge conflict that never happened (but should have)"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180313-00/?p=98225) I suppose one can fake that by having a filter that always appends something to your file, which would force the merge driver to activate.

Comment: @Fizz 9 years after having written this answer, I agree. This is not exactly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a setting file like `setting-sample`, and modify `.gitignore` to ignore the real setting file (i.e. `setting`). So the empty setting file will be kept in remote repo, and your personal setting file will be kept in your local repo.

Answer (score 1):

You may commit the empty settings file and then commit a .gitignore file pointing to the original file, so in that case, the users would download the file but git will ignore the changes that users make.

Comment: I think so, can you try it out?