# Whats the Proper usage of .gitattributes with merge=ours

Tags: git, merge, attributes, bitbucket

I just tried using .gitattributes for the first time.  I figure I must be doing something wrong because it is not working as I thought the purpose of using the `merge=ours` attribute was intended for (?).

An example of my usage:

I have two branches; one is the "master" and the other is "GCE-Site". There are files on the "GCE-Site" branch that have different settings that also exists on the "master" branch that I do not want merging into the "master" [or other branches].

On both branches, I have a `.gitattributes` containing the following rules:

```
README.md merge=ours
config.php merge=ours
.gitattributes merge=ours
.gitignore merge=ours
.cache/ merge=ours
```

All the files needing the rules are on the root level plus everything above the .cache/ folder. When I do a `git merge GCE-Site`, all files still merge into the master when I don't want that.

Is there something I am missing? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thnx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easy fix once I knew what I was doing: I missed adding the merge strategy with `git config --global merge.ours.driver true` in my local environment.

Comment: I believe this will not work if a merge can be performed with fast forward.

Comment: i see this and try but this is not workd for me sooo plzz any help you? marge time both file marge how to solved?

Comment: This works locally when merging one branch into another, but when I create a github.com website pull request, github ignores the .gitattributes file. Anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in "[.gitattributes & individual merge strategy for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5895890/6309)":

> The merge driver is only called in non-trivial cases, i.e. if both master and test have touched setup (and you need to define the merge driver ours first).

You can see an example of concurrent modification (ie modification in both branches) in "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309)".

So if your merges didn't involve modifications of the same files within `cache/` folder in both branches, your merge driver was never called.

But in your case, for files with different settings, I would recommend not using a merge driver, but a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309), as in "[Keep settings in branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571881/6309)"

[image: content filter driver]

That allows you to keep in version control:

- template file for the settings in the `cache/` folder
- a script able to take a template file and replace the value placeholders with the right value depending on the branch checked out.