# How can I ignore the entire bower_components directory when merging with git?

Tags: git, merge

I have a project set up with Ionic Framework, and started working off of the master branch, setting up my own branch to do so on a branch called updates. There's also another branch called rc1-2015 that I'm trying to merge into the updates branch, but a lot of the bower components (and platforms directory) got updated in my updates branch, causing merge conflicts in nearly every file.

I want to keep all the bower components from the updates branch as they are now, but merge all the rest of the files. I've tried adding `bower_components/* merge=ours` to `.gitattributes` but it doesn't seem to do anything, there are still tons of merge conflicts.

How can I make it ignore the `bower_components` dir (and the `platforms` dir), but merge the rest of the files?

Comment: Why not just `.gitignore` the `bower_components` folder?

Comment: use `.gitignore` then

Comment: I did that and it still gives me the merge conflicts because they've already been committed at one point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Whats the Proper usage of .gitattributes with merge=ours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27280094/6309)", don' t forget to activate the merge strategy:

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

Comment: I was forgetting this, but it's still not solving my problem. Do I need to commit the `.gitattributes` file first or something? My `.gitattributes` file only contains one line: `bower_components/* merge=ours`. I've tried with two asterisks, and just `bower_components/`.

Comment: @Jared yes, the .gitattributes needs to be committed.

Comment: I did that, but still getting merge conflicts in the bower_components dir. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm ready to start pulling my hair out...

Comment: @Jared see a full example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309, with a committed .gitattributes.