# Ignore some files during branch merging

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I have two branches **master** and **develop**. Each branch contains a same file named "**db.config**" having a separate db credentials for production(master) and staging(develop).

Master branch also have **.gitattributes** file in which i defined a merge=ours strategy for **db.config**

**.gitattributes**

`db.config merge=ours`

When i merge **develop** into **master** branch by creating a pull request in bitbucket then changes in develop branch also goes to master after merge for db.config. It looks like **.gitattributes** file doesnot work for me.

Also [stackoverflow same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge) doesnot works for me. Does anyone know how i get rid out of this?

Comment: TL;DR: you *can't* ignore a file during merge. Using `.gitattributes` doesn't do that. *Sometimes*, by defining a merge driver, you can cause the *effect* of a merge to be what you want. The file was not ignored! This *sometimes* does not apply at all times, Don't do this, you'll just make your own life miserable.

Comment: @torek is their any other way to do this in our actual project?

Comment: Not really. In general, files that aren't meant to be merged should never be committed in the first place. Configurations should have *prototype* or *example* files committed; the actual configuration should be stored elsewhere, not in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to replicate your issue, and pretty sure you forgot that part:

And then define a dummy ours merge strategy with:

```
$ git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

From your master branch.

Switch to master, configure your merge strategy, it should work.

[Whats the Proper usage of .gitattributes with merge=ours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134100/whats-the-proper-usage-of-gitattributes-with-merge-ours)

Edit: due to what had been said in the comments, you probably want to remove this file from tracking:

[How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I also tried this but it doesnot worked when i am creating a pull  request and then merge a branch in bitbucket using default merge strategy.

Comment: @Jawad don't forget that PR merges remotely so `git config --global merge.ours.driver true` has no effect in PR