# git attributes for merge=ours doesn't work

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, gitattributes

I am using Sourcetree 3.0.12 on Windows. The command-line git version I'm using is `git version 2.18.0.windows.1` (at least that's what it says when I open the Terminal from Sourcetree and get the Cygwin command line).

I want all the files on `app/Resources/` in my tree to be "protected" from changes in other branches; in other words, I want git to always merge my version in that folder. So I did the following:

1) In the command line, at the root of the tree, I typed `git config --global merge.ours.driver true`.

2) At the root of my tree I created a `.gitattributes` file that said:

```
app/Resources/ merge=ours
```

Then I try to merge a change in another branch... and I get a lot of conflicts in files in `app/Resources`.

I read around an offhand comment suggesting that this feature only works with a newer version of git. Is that the case, or did I do something wrong?

EDIT: following the first answer below, I edited by hand my `.git/config` file to add this:

```
[merge "ours"]
    name = ours
    driver = true
```

I added it at the end of the file, then I tried merging again... but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to define a custom merge driver there. The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/2.27.0) tell that you should do this in another file, then reference it. This holds even in version 2.18.0.

> The definition of a merge driver is done in the `.git/config` file, not
>   in the `gitattributes` file, so strictly speaking this manual page is a
>   wrong place to talk about it. [ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/2.27.0#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver)

If I have a look at the [examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/2.27.0#_examples), I see that:

```
ab* merge=filfre
abc -foo -bar
*.c frotz
```

Where that `filfre` was defined in the git config file. This should at least address the part 2 of your question, I'd advice you to try this different approach there.

For part 1, `git config --global merge.ours.driver true` was given as accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134100/whats-the-proper-usage-of-gitattributes-with-merge-ours), although I feel like the other answer is way more accurate. Indeed, the accepted answer is by the original question author, and doesn't provide much inside. A known corner case is also available where the fix doesn't work. Have you considered the [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27234774/2125110)?

Comment: You mean using content filters? That doesn't really work in my case, I think. The two branches have two sets of templates for different websites that share one backend engine; in other words, there are too many different files for that to work (at least if I understand the feature...)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
app/Resources/* merge=ours
```

in your `.gitattributes`.