# Git merge apply incoming changes only for unmodified files

Tags: git, merge

Is there any way to merge two branches while keeping "ours" changes for changed files (added, modified, deleted etc) and getting "theirs" version for all the rest (unchanged in my branch files).

What have i tried:

1. "-X ours" works only for conflicts and if there is no conflict it tries to merge file contents and i want exactly "ours" version for such cases.
2. "-s ours" takes "ours" version for every file, even if it was not changed and i want unchanged in my branch files to be overwritten.

There should be some combination of those two but im having a hard time finding it.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you getting conflicts?

Comment: @evolutionxbox when i do it works ok with "-X ours", but if there is no conflict it merges two file versions recursively and i want  "ours" version for such cases too. Only case when it's ok to get "theirs" is when file was not changed in my branch at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There should be some combination of [the `-s ours` *strategy*, and the `-X ours` *eXtended strategy option*] ...

Whether or not there should be, there isn't.  (You *could* write your own, but this would be a big task.)  You may be able to get close enough with an *ours driver*, which has nothing to do with the `ours` *strategy*.  Read the long description below to see what this means.  See [Whats the Proper usage of .gitattributes with merge=ours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27134100/1256452) and [tell git to use ours merge strategy on specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14093540/1256452) for examples of this.

#### Long

It is, at this point, worth describing the mechanics behind `git merge`.  You run:

```
git merge [-s <strategy>] [-X <extended-options> ...] <commit-specifier>
```

—there are other options but I'm ignoring them entirely for this particular answer—and the `-s` option, if specified, chooses the *strategy* to use, while the `-X` option(s), if specified, are passed on *to* this strategy.  (That's why Git calls them *strategy options*, but to make sense of the `-X` flag, I call them *extended strategy options* or simply *extended options*.)

The commit specifier—often a branch name—is required here, though technically even that is optional (Git will merge the branch with its *upstream* if you don't name a particular commit), and for certain merge strategies, you can name *more than one* commit or branch here.  Again, we aren't looking into those cases now; we're just concerned with the single-other-commit, "two branches get merged" type merge.

The way `git merge` itself starts out is pretty simple: it inspects the options you've supplied to make sure they make sense, makes some preliminary checks to make sure the merge can proceed, and then—this is just before things get complicated—it *invokes the merge strategy you chose*:

- If you ran `git merge -s ours`, `git merge` runs `git-merge-ours`.
- If you ran `git merge -s resolve`, `git merge` runs `git-merge-resolve`.
- If you ran `git merge -s recursive`, or didn't specify a `-s` strategy, `git merge` runs `git-merge-recursive`.

**Everything after this point is up to the merge strategy.**  Well, *mostly* everything: Git runs the strategy, and then the strategy signals back to `git merge` whether the merge worked and it should go ahead and make a merge commit.  (This means the front end can implement the `--no-commit` and `--squash` options; the various strategies don't need to know about this stuff, saving work in the various strategy source codes.)

The `-s ours` strategy, as you have seen, is ridiculously simple: it completely ignores the other commit and makes a new merge commit whose contents match the current commit as seen on the current branch.  For `git merge -s ours otherbranch`, this merges the branches while tossing out all of their work entirely.

The default *recursive* strategy, along with its sister strategy called *resolve*, do a lot more work.  They:

- find a merge base;
- figure out what we changed on the current branch since that merge base;
- figure out what they changed on their branch since that merge base;
- **combines** their changes with our changes;
- gets all the files *from* the merge base; and
- applies the *combined* changes to those files.

If all goes well with the combining, the merge is done and Git makes a new merge commit as usual.  If there are *conflicts*, the merge stops with the conflict, and makes you finish the job.

The *extended* arguments, if any, are passed to each of the various strategies.  The recursive and resolve strategies use `-X ours` or `-X theirs` to *automatically resolve* some conflicts.  These flags only apply to what I call *low-level conflicts*, i.e., conflicting changes within some file(s).

**This is not what you are looking for.**  What you have asked for is a strategy that, upon discovering that some file is modified in *both branch tips* as compared to the merge base, will take the "ours" *file* (or lack thereof in case of a deletion) and *completely ignore the changes they made* to that file with respect to the shared merge base.  But, if we did not touch the file and they did, you want this strategy to take *their file*.

The bad news is that *you must write this merge strategy yourself*.

The good news is that this strategy is simple enough that you could write it in, probably, a few dozen lines of shell script.

The bad news is that this strategy won't handle renames very well, though it's up to you to find the renames in the first place.  (My guess is that handling renames well would at least triple or quadruple the number of shell-script lines required, or force you into using a more powerful programming language to write your strategy.  You can write your strategy in any language you like.)

The really bad news, though, is that writing a strategy is *hard*.  It's also quite undocumented: it's not entirely clear what the parameters *to* the strategy are.  You'll need to look through the Git source code to figure it out, and it may depend on Git version.

**Note that using a *merge driver* might, suffice for your particular use case**, provided you don't really care about things like modify/delete and rename/rename (i.e., non-low-level) conflicts.  But you explicitly mentioned "added, modified, deleted".  Except for modify/modify, these are *high-level* or *tree-level* modifications; merge drivers only get called for modify/modify cases.

**In the particular case where both branch-tips modified some file with respect to the version that appears in the merge base commit**, the resolve and recursive strategies will invoke a defined *merge driver*.  The default merge driver is essentially the one in [the `git merge-file` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file): the `git merge-file` command is basically a wrapper for the built-in merge driver.  This is the one that produces conflict markers.

To define *your own* merge driver, you must:

- define the driver itself in your `.git/config` or global gitconfig file;
- declare that some particular set of files should *use* that driver, via your `.gitattributes` file(s).

At this point, `-s resolve` or the default `-s recursive` will use your merge driver for cases where the copy of the file in the merge base commit differs from the copy in the current commit *and* differs from the copy in the other commit.  It won't invoke your merge driver for other cases, so it would suffice to set the result to be the "ours commit" file.

Comment: I'll stick to identifying changed files (with diff by merge-base) and using "merge --no-commit" with "checkout filename" for every changed file. Thank you for the great answer!